# fill up a numeric variable in data.table efficiently by id

Tags: r, data.table

As a natural consequence of the `data.table` subsetting logic in `i`, I often end up in situations where I have part of a variable defined for an id (like "total economic crises before 2007 per country" being counted for data < 2007 hence NA for anything later). Here is a slightly more general example:

```
library("data.table")
Data <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 4),
                   variable =c(3,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

When I subsequently need this variable defined over the entire dataset, I want to fill up the NA's by group. I usually do this using max by group:

```
Data[, variable_full := max(variable, na.rm = T), by = id]
Data[variable_full == -Inf, variable_full := NA] # this just overwrites the result of the warning
```

But, for whatever reason, this takes very long in large datasets. Is there a more efficient, more `data.table` like way of doing this?

edit: "large datasets" is currently 8 million observations and it stops my workflow because it takes several minutes. Other data.table operations take split seconds because `data.table` is amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the collapse package, I think this could be much faster:

```
library(collapse)
Data = Data |> gby(id) |> fmutate(variable_full=fmax(variable)) |> setDT()
```

gby is 'group by' and fmutate is 'fast mutate'.  The default output is a grouped data frame so it needs the 'setDT' at the end

Comment: by a factor of 18 in my current dataset of 23 million observations. Amazing...

Answer (score 1):

perhaps a join?

```
Data[, variable_full := variable]
Data[is.na(variable), variable_full := Data[!is.na(variable), 
                                       max(variable), 
                                       by = .(id)][Data[is.na(variable), ], V1, on = .(id)]][]
```

a (slightly) shorter version of the line with the join is

```
Data[is.na(variable), variable_full := Data[!is.na(variable), max(variable), by = .(id)][.SD, V1, on = .(id)]]
```

here, the `[Data[is.na(variable), ],`  part has bene replaced with `[.SD,` , because is is alreadaey derived from i (at the beginning of the line)...

the

Comment: The only speed improvement here  can come from the is.na(variable) part, correct? I was hoping for something simpler, this also needs another line like Data[is.na(variable), variable := variable_full], right?

Comment: The first line is the initailisation of `variable_full`, the join then changes it by reference.

Comment: wow, that solution is 200 times faster compared to my attempt. Thanks! If someone can come up with something that has a simpler syntax, that would be great though, this is very hard to read I think.